# Are diffeomorphisms induced by non-autonomous flows the same as autonomous flows on a compact subset?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, diffeomorphism

Short version (as suggested by Mariano, and as in title):

For every diffeomorphism $f: \Omega \rightarrow \Omega$, (where $\Omega$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$) that is the time-1 map of a "non-autonomous flow", is it also the time-1 map of an autonomous flow?

---

Consider the following situation:

For $x \in \Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ where $\Omega$ is compact,  Let $\phi(x, t)$ be defined by the following boundary conditions:
$$ \phi(x, 0) = x, \quad \phi(x, 1) = f(x), \quad f \in C^\infty $$

and the differential equation:
$$ \frac{d \phi(x, t)}{dt} = v(\phi(x, t), t) $$

Of course, the set of functions $v(\phi(x, t))$ is a proper subset of $v(\phi(x, t), t)$. I'm trying to find a $v$ that satisfies the ODE and boundary conditions.

My question is, is there some $f(x)$ for which the differential equation
$$ \frac{d \phi(x, t)}{dt} = v(\phi(x, t), t) $$
has a solution but

$$ \frac{d \phi(x, t)}{dt} = v(\phi(x, t)) $$
does not?

Comment: I've edited the mistake about $f$. The only useful thing about $\Omega$ is that its compact, so the optimization is not done over the entire open set $\mathbb{R}^n$.


$v$ is used to define the flow of the particles whose locations are $\phi(x, t)$ at time t. The intuition behind my question is: if I know the initial and final locations of a bunch of particles within a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$,  is there a final configuration of particles (\phi(x, 1) = f(x)) which a stationary (autonomous) velocity cannot represent, but a non-stationary (nonautonomous) can?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I wanted to ask. the diffeomorphisms I'm interested in only have support over $\Omega$. Also $f: \Omega \rightarrow \Omega$ right?

Comment: You can make relaxations on some of the assumptions. I'm broadly interested in $\Omega$ that are regular grids. Some of the theorems in Younnes' book start with an open set $\Omega$ and show properties on its closure later on.

this is from Xavier Pennec's book.  https://imgur.com/a/4xaybSL  (diffeomorphisms on $\Omega$ to $\Omega$)